# Equivalence class for non-equivalence relations

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I have a homogeneuos relation $R\subseteq X\times Y,\,\, X
=Y$ that is

1. symmetric
2. reflexive
3. not transitive

What is $[x]_R = \{y:(x,y)\in R\}$ called and what is the proper notation if not $[x]_R$?

I have another relation $S\subseteq X\times Y,X=Y$ that is

1. antisymmetric
2. reflexive
3. transitive

What is the transitive closure of $S$ given x called and denoted? (If you know what I mean...)

Comment: What do you mean by 'not $[x]_R$'? As you've written, $[x]_R$ is a set.

Comment: We can call it the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Definition) of $x$ under $R$.

Comment: I just pretended like I know it should be denoted $[x]_R$ but actually I don't know that. So is it correct notation or is there a different notation?

Comment: Sometimes it is used $R‘‘A$ for the *image of the set* $A$ *under* $R$. Thus, we may write $R‘‘ \{ x \} = \{ y \mid xRy \}$.

Comment: As far as I can tell your link to wikipedia refers to a function, but my relation R is not a function...

Comment: $X=Y$ is needed here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.

Comment: So I can also write R[x]?

Comment: No I do not know what you mean by the run on phrase "given x and called."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $R[A]=\{y \mid \exists x\in A,(x,y)\in R \}$ is called the [*image of a set* $A$ *under a relation* $R$](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Set_Theory/Relations).

Thus, we have $R[ \{ x \} ]$ and we can "simplify" it to $R[x]$.

Sometimes also used: $R‘‘A$; in this case we may write $R‘‘ \{ x \}$.